# Fedora won't boot in UEFI

Tags: fedora, filesystems, uefi

So I decided to replace the operating system on my laptop. I used to have **Manjaro Linux** installed with **UEFI** mode and it worked fine. Now I decided to install Fedora.

I first live booted Fedora Workstation up in UEFI from USB. Every thing worked fine. Then I launched the official installer and selected automatic disk partitioning. The installation was successful. I restarted my computer. When it booted up it coudn't detect any bootable media. Becouse of that, I decided to reinstall the system with manual partitioning. I created a **gpt** partition table with 2 partitions; **efi system partition** mounted at */boot/efi* formatted with fat-32 and a **root partition** formated with ext4 and mounted at */*. The efi partition has the **efi** flag set and is 500MiB. The install went through fine, but the system still doesn't boot.

I then tried several more times with little adjusments and no luck. I tried installing the system with same configurations in virtual box with UEFI (yes I checked the *Enable EFI (special OSes only))* and it worked every time. Maybe faulty laptop?

**Do you have any *suggestions* what might I have done wrong, or what might the problem be?**

Answer (score 3):

On UEFI, the bootloader is normally identified by the unique UUID of the EFI system partition and the bootloader file pathname, both stored into UEFI boot variables in system NVRAM. Unlike with old MBR-style boot, just specifying the disk to boot from is not necessarily enough.

Some system manufacturers have designed their UEFI firmware with a built-in assumption that the OS will be Windows, and added a "helpful" feature that will reset the UEFI boot variables to the exact values used by Windows.

Start by booting the system to rescue mode **in UEFI mode**. Then run `efibootmgr -v` as root. That will tell you the current state of the UEFI boot variables. You can also use the `blkid` command to list the filesystem and partition UUIDs of each disk the system has. The partition UUID (listed in `blkid` output as `PARTUUID=<value>`) of the EFI system partition should match the UUID listed in the boot variables listed by `efibootmgr -v` command. If necessary, you can use other options with `efibootmgr` to fix the contents of the boot variables. See `man efibootmgr` for details.

(Note: the UEFI firmware uses *partition* UUIDs, while the GRUB bootloader can use *filesystem* UUIDs. The `blkid` lists the former as `PARTUUID=` and the latter as `UUID=`. Don't confuse the two.)

If you find that the UEFI boot variables don't point to the Fedora bootloader and that any changes you make won't stick over a reboot, then you very likely have some variation of the UEFI firmware bug I mentioned earlier. Roderick W. Smith calls this a *boot coup*: [see this link for a list of some known variations and workarounds for them.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html)

Basically, one possible workaround is to set up (a copy of) the bootloader into either the standard removable-disk-boot path on the EFI system partition (`\EFI\boot\boot<arch>.efi`, where `<arch>` is typically `x64` or possibly `ia32` on typical PC hardware. Another is to place the Linux UEFI bootloader into the same path Windows normally uses (`\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`).

Comment: Getting through his http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/ article might be helpful either!